# Hot Swappable Pullup IC or Standard Circuit

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, pullup

I am designing a circuit that will interface to many different devices and sometimes the I/O line require a pullup resistor (1kohm) and sometimes not. There are also 7 I/I lines. I need this to be configurable, controlled by an on board MCU (STM32F4). The MCU I have has internal pullups but they are too high of a value.

Digging around the internet, I found this IC:
https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Diodes%20PDFs/PI5L102.pdf

Its pretty close to what I want in an IC but I would like a stronger pullup. Before finding this, the initial idea was to connect a PMOSFET to my rail (where I will pullup to) and have the MCU control that to connect and disconnect pullup resistors as it makes to do. Aside from the IC I found, is there a more practical way to do this? Is there a standard way? Or is just using a PMOSFET for each resistor the best way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A three-state buffer to control the pull-ups
2. Analog switch
3. Unused MCU pins to directly control the pull-up

Comment: The unused MCU pins was a thought I had but I didn't think it was a legit way of doing but apparently it is! You are suggesting that when I want to enable the pullup, I drive the pin to that resistor high, and when I want to disable the pullup, I turn that pin into a high impedance by making it an input?

Comment: Yes, that's one way of doing it for example.

Comment: Ok I will give this a shot in my design. Thank you for your input.